# How to pass a member function to a gloabal function in cpp?

Tags: c++, templates, generics

Im on a Cpp beginner project. making a library system. And I wrote the following `void Student::show(void)` function to show student's details. Also I have written the first function to avoid repeating. I want to pass the `create` function to the `printAtEnd` function as a argument. But it gives me some errors. What I did wrong here.

```cpp
// conclusion menu
template <typename R, typename A, typename C>
// R - return type
// A - argument type
// C - class type
void printAtEnd(R (C::*func)(A)){
    int i;
    cout << "Choose one of following.\n";
    cout << "\t1. go to main menu.\n";
    cout << "\t2. try again.\n";
    cout << "\t3. exit the program\n";
    cin >> i;

    switch(i){
        case 1: mainMenu(); break;
        case 2: func(); break;
        case 3: exit(0); break;
    }
}


void Student::show(void){
     system("clear");
     cout << "\tStudent details\n\n";
 
     cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
     cout << "Addmission No: " << addmission_no << endl;
     cout << "Email: " << email << endl;
     cout << "Telephone No: " << telephone_no << endl;
     cout << "Issued books: \n";
     for (string x: issued_books)
         cout << x << endl;
 
     printAtEnd<void, void, Student>(&Student::show);
}
```

I get following error when compiling.

```
library.cpp: In member function ‘void Student::show()’:
library.cpp:151:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘printAtEnd<void, void, Student>(void (Student::*)())’
  151 |     printAtEnd<void, void, Student>(&Student::show);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
library.cpp:79:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class R, class A, class C> void printAtEnd(R (C::*)(A))’
   79 | void printAtEnd(R (C::*func)(A)){
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~
library.cpp:79:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
library.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class R, class A, class C> void printAtEnd(R (C::*)(A)) [with R = void; A = void; C = Student]’:
library.cpp:151:36:   required from here
library.cpp:79:6: error: invalid parameter type ‘void’
library.cpp:79:6: error: in declaration ‘void printAtEnd(R (C::*)(A))’
```

All I want is call `printAtEnd` function after every other functions. So I need to pass the pointer to a function to `printAtEnd` function.

Comment: You need to call `func` on *an object*.  What object is the `func` method being called on?

Comment: @Eljay could you please elaborate?

Comment: Have you tried using a **static_cast** ?

Comment: If you want to get help, then you should provide the error message. If you cannot take 20 seconds to make a better question, then don't expect people to take time to answer you.

Comment: The main problem is that theire is no such thing a void argument. An `void` type argument A is not the same thing as no argument. Thus you need to remove `A` type and argument from `printAtEnd` function template.

Comment: Once this is fixed, the other problem is that you cannot call `func()` because you don't have the object on which the function should be called. The syntax would be `(student->func)();` and you must provide the variable `Student *student` somehow.

Comment: @Phil1970 Then how to deal with function that takes a argument. How to pass them to this function?

Comment: Obviously, you cannot use the same template (for 0 or 1 argument) or you have to use variadic template (for an arbitrary number of arguments).

Comment: @ Phil1970 For calling of the function I can use `this` keyword in the member function. Can't I?

Comment: There is no `this` inside `printAtEnd`. By the way, why are you using pointer to member function. This is something adavanced that is very rarely used in practice. Even less, with `std::function` and lambda. `void printAtEnd(std::function<void ()> fn)` would be a more flexible approach here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing useless code from the question, it could be something like:

```
void printAtEnd(std::function<void ()> fn)
{
    fn();
}
 
void Student::show()
{
    printAtEnd([this](){ this->show(); });
}
```

However, the problem with your code it that it is recursive and if the user always select the option 2, you might eventually get a stack overflow if you run on some small memory device.

In a case like this one, a loop would usually be a better option.

Comment: Well this work on the above test case but not in any other function unless they return void and get no argument. right?

Comment: And if you have arguments, you have to know them at that point... So what is the problem?  `void Student::show(int arg1) { printAtEnd([this, &arg1](){ this->show(arg1); }); }`

Comment: Thank you so much. You made my day!